# npm mulfunction after node 5.0.0 install with OSX El Capitan

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

Any `npm` command(except `npm -v` which is 3.3.6)  returns something like:

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module './lib'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to completely remove npm (uninstall nodejs and install it without npm)
and after that use
`curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh`

here is an instructions
https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689